# compile directive inside directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a [HighlightJS](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs) directive on `<pre>` blocks rendered by a [Markdown](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive) directive.

*Here is an plunker recreating the problem:*
http://plnkr.co/edit/qZlMkjNZglV453caNphy?p=preview

In this example:

```
<btf-markdown>
#Markdown directive
<pre hljs>

    angular.forEach($scope.items,function(item){
      console.log(item);
    });
</pre>
</btf-markdown>
```

I would expect the `<pre>` block to get parsed by `hljs` but does not.

Do I have to manually invoke the compilation of the inner directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `btford.markdown` your `element.html(html);` is overwriting the `hljs`

So instead of:

```
var html = converter.makeHtml(element.text());
element.html(html);
```

I think you'd prefer:

```
var html = converter.makeHtml(element.html());
element.html(html);
```

switching `element.text()` with `element.html()`

So you're converting the whole html element (including your `hljs` - which isn't in `element.text()`).

Here's the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cURJ1QRfJRheOxTvYc1p?p=preview

Comment: Although this enables the `hljs` directive to compile, the `btf-markdown` directive falls through. Perhaps there was something else in the plunker you forked that made these two play nice together?

Comment: Nope- you're right.  I think I see what you're doing more clearly now.  I updated the answer- see if this is closer.

Comment: I have a good follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983086/compile-a-directive-passed-from-a-scoped-variable-consumed-by-another-directive

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out [Angular Marked](https://github.com/Hypercubed/angular-marked), which is based on btford work.

- You can use it as a service, which means you can parse strings in controllers, directives, for subsequent processing,
- It supports some [Github Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/), which allows for easy table creation, [see here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables).