# compile a directive passed from a scoped variable consumed by another directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a [HighlightJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959267/compile-directive-inside-directive-angularjs) directive on `<pre>` blocks rendered by a [Markdown](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive) directive from a scoped variable, which is a follow up from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959267/compile-directive-inside-directive-angularjs)

*Here is an plunker recreating the problem:*
http://plnkr.co/edit/9dFxvDpCx5Qn68Mk0uiv?p=preview

The `markdown` directive will compile `hljs` from `element.html()` --- that is:

```
<btf-markdown>
#Markdown directive
<pre hljs>

    angular.forEach($scope.items,function(item){
      console.log(item);
    });
</pre>
</btf-markdown>
```

However evaluating `hljs` from a scoped variable it falls through:

```
<div btf-markdown="item">
</div>
```

How do I compile a directive passed from a scoped variable consumed by another directive?

Comment: how about $compile? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle . Basically, you just `$compile` any html that you want and `append` it to the new position.

Here is an updated plunk with that working. If you put in a `pre` inside the text area with `hljs` it should work fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vZ2VlVCdSQWGBtgXLSAW?p=preview